# Не получается создать foreign key

Tags: sql

Не понимаю как сделать форинкей.Есть первая таблица:

```
postgres=# select * from MyWriters;

 writerid |      name
----------+----------------
        4 | Vitaliy Zukov
        5 | Garry Garrison
        6 | Nick Perumov
```

Cоздаю вторую, но когда пытаюсь на один и тот же айдишник повесить разные книги,
то вылазит ошибка, мол такой айдишник существует.

```
postgres=# create table NoBooks (
postgres(# bookID int not null primary key,
postgres(# name varchar(100),
postgres(# foreign key (bookID) references MyWriters(writerID)
postgres(# );
CREATE TABLE


postgres=# insert into NoBooks (bookID, name) values (4, 'Malk');
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# insert into NoBooks (bookID, name) values (4, 'Bezumiannuy rab');
```

> ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "nobooks_pkey"
> DETAIL:  Key (bookid)=(4) already exists.

Comment: Вы добавляете запись `... values (4, 'Malk')`, потом вторую -> `values (4, 'Bezumiannuy rab')`, указывая при этом первый параметр (bookID) одинаковый, но он у вас = `bookID int not null primary key`, т.е. не может дублироваться... Но вы впридачу на id навесили ещё и foreign key. Это не корректно. Добавьте для таблицы NoBooks поле автора `writerID int not null` и уже на это поле вешайте foreign key аля `...foreign key (writerID) references MyWriters(writerID)...` и при добавлении, соответственно, указывайте автора: `insert into NoBooks (bookID, name, writerID) values (4, 'Malk', 4)`

Comment: И, чисто моё имхо, если у вас таблицы называется writers то в ней не должно быть поля writer_id ибо это и так поле в этой таблице.. writer_id поле должно называться в другой таблице, если там присутствует связь какая-то с таблицей writers

Answer (score 2):

Надо добавить еще один столбец `NoBooks.writerID`, это и будет внешний ключ:

```
foreign key (writerID) references MyWriters(writerID)
```

Благодаря комментарию [@InDevX](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1147473/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-foreign-key/1179878#comment1987210_1147473)